# How to create a linux terminal ASCII character logo?

Tags: linux, centos7

I'm a newbie to Linux. I want to create my own ASCII character logo to be displayed on the Linux terminal(it is for pleasure and also to learn). I searched through the internet and found there are tools available for that work. For example,Figlet,Neofetch,Screenfetch etc. But I want to know if there is any method to create a such a logo except hard-coding the logo. If anyone know please help.

Comment: Please allow us to DuckDuckGo that for you: [dynamic ascii art site:stackoverflow.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dynamic+ascii+art+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: @jww Are you saying that using a bitmap? I didn't get your point. I want this to be printed on my linux terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You're much more likely to get an answer if you explain clearly.

By 'ASCII character logo' you could mean that you want to create your own character (as in letter/number/symbol) and use it in the terminal just like you'd be able to display the 'L' letter. For that you'd need to create your own font, add your character in and set the terminal to use that font. There are plenty of tools online that can help you create a font.

If you mean you simply want to display some ascii art on the terminal, you can use something like this: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20. You can save the text to a file on your linux computer, and print it back out again using the `cat` command.

An example is below:

```
cat ascii_logo.txt
```

You do also list things like figet, which will automatically generate the ASCII art for you from some text - I'm not sure why these don't fulfill your needs?

Comment: Your method also fine @Bobby Dilley. "I'm not sure why these don't fulfill your needs?" - yes because I want to know if there any methods other than using those tools.